# Incorrect id after Eloquent save call

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, mariadb

In the production environment which is using `MariaDB 10.3.8`, id is `0` after calling `save` method from model.

Table has an auto incrementing `id` column with `unsigned integer` type

Comment: Please post the model.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause to be 'laravel/telescope' package after some googling.
After disabling that package it worked as usual.

More on this issue can be found in https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/289